# github downloads - can it only be a flat file system?

Tags: github

I need to make binaries and documentation available for a github project which is currently on SourceForge. There, I am able to have a directory structure for the downloads which I need as I have to provide a few versions for about 10 different OSes. The Downloads section in github seems to only be one flat-file "directory" - is this correct? It would be impossible/very messy for me to be able to have no subdirectory structure for downloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. Github is not really the place to distribute binary files. You should just stick with SourceForge.

Comment: github also ended the support for binary downloads a few time ago, see: https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple "directories", although the result isn't very human-friendly for browsing.  But for some things it might not be the worst solution.  Here is a proof-of-concept example of a Maven repo deployed to the Downloads section https://github.com/lukewpatterson/travis-deployment-key-demo/downloads